# Set <h2> text based on table cells - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, each

I'm trying to loop through 8 **h2's** of class **.attr-lbl**, and set their text to a corresponding top 8 **td's** of class **.t0_rhc** in a table. So basically the 1st instance of a **h2** needs to be set to the first instance of a **td** and so on. In this example the first **h2** would be set to **TEXT 1**, the second to **TEXT 2** and so on.

I have tried an `.each()` loop but it keeps setting all **h2's** to the same value (i.e TEXT 1) - here is what I have so far:

```
<h2 class="attr-lbl"></h2>
<h2 class="attr-lbl"></h2>
<!-- ...etc -->

<td class="t0_rhc">TEXT 1</td>
<td class="t0_rhc">TEXT 2</td>
<!-- ...etc -->
```

```js
var count = 0;
$('h2.attr-lbl').each(function() {
    var title = $('td.t0_rhc').eq(count).text();
    $('h2.attr-lbl').text(title);
    count++;
});
```

How can I keep the function moving down the table for each h2 element? Thanks in advance, happy to elaborate if necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you require count variable ?

Just use **`each()`** for element that you want to iterate and use the **`eq()`**.

```
$('td.t0_rhc').each(function(key, value) {
  $('h2.attr-lbl').eq(key).text($(this).text());
});
```

```js
$('span.t0_rhc').each(function(key, value) {
  $('h2.attr-lbl').eq(key).text($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="attr-lbl"></h2>
<h2 class="attr-lbl"></h2>
<h2 class="attr-lbl"></h2>

<span class="t0_rhc">TEXT 1</span>
<span class="t0_rhc">TEXT 2</span>
<span class="t0_rhc">TEXT 3</span>
```

Comment: Fantastic! Yeah I thought it was probably redundant. I'm not 100% sure how key / value auto increments but it works so thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You should be context sensitive. Use `this`:

```
var count = 0;
$('h2.attr-lbl').each(function() {
    var title = $('td.t0_rhc').eq(count).text();
    $(this).text(title);
    count++;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this does make sense but unfortunately doesn't work! Is there something I need to pass in the function parameter of each() maybe?

Comment: @Andyjm Would you like to show a working snippet? So that we can better understand where the problem comes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.text(fn)`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function) and use the `index` of current element to get the text from relevant `span`

```
$('h2.attr-lbl').text(function(index, _) {
  return $('span.t0_rhc:eq(' + index + ')').text();
});
```

```js
$('h2.attr-lbl').text(function(index, _) {
  return $('span.t0_rhc:eq(' + index + ')').text();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="attr-lbl"></h2>
<h2 class="attr-lbl"></h2>

<span class="t0_rhc">TEXT 1</span>
<span class="t0_rhc">TEXT 2</span>
```